# Laravel PHP get value in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this array called "images"

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => {#371 ▼
    +"id": 15175604535432
    +"product_id": 4673356234888
    +"position": 1
    +"created_at": "2020-03-10T16:52:33-04:00"
    +"updated_at": "2020-03-10T16:52:33-04:00"
    +"alt": null
    +"width": 800
    +"height": 800
    +"src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0335/4175/0920/products/product-image-1294465746.jpg?v=1583873553"
    +"variant_ids": []
    +"admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/15175604535432"
  }
  1 => {#372 ▶}
  2 => {#373 ▶}
  3 => {#374 ▶}
  4 => {#375 ▶}
  5 => {#376 ▶}
```

and I know that I need src of images where 'id' has value 15175604535432.

Is there a way to get src if I know value of ID?

I already try `dd($products[1]->images['id'][15175604535432]->src);`
and `$products[1]->images->where('id',15175604535432)->src` but both didnt work

Comment: Show the error you are receiving.

Comment: Error: Undefined index: id and Call to a member function where() on array for the second code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Collection with that array and use the Collection methods to find your record, if you wanted to:

```
$image = collect($products[1]->images)->where('id', $id)->first();

$src = $image ? $image->src : null;
```

Comment: can you please tell me does your solution is faster or memory saver than this: <?php
foreach( $p->images as $obj ) {
    if( $obj->id == $v->image_id ) {
        // Do your thing
        $image = $obj->src; // The `src` attr. is on the same level as the id attr. 
        break;
    }
}
?> ....

Comment: I mean does collect() is better to use than for each loop to find the element?

Answer (score 0):

1. You know in what index of the image is and you want to retrieve its src:

```
$images[1]->src // gives src of image in given index
```

2. You can loop through every index:

```
$id =  "15175604535432";
$imageSrc = null;

foreach( $images as $image ) {
    if( $image->id == $id ) {
        $imageSrc = $image->src; 
        break;
    }
}

if( $imageSrc != null ) {
    // src found
}
```

You can also make an collection, but you only need one value.

So with collection you iterate over the array with “->first()” until you find the first matching value.

Finally you create a new object only for retrieving one value.

This are a few more steps then a foreach loop thus it is more expansive.

But it does looks “prettier”.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$image_src = "";

foreach($images as $image) {

    if($image->id == "15175604535432") {
     
        $image_src .= $image->src;

    }

}

dd($image_src);exit;
```